# Delete multiple selected items in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, multiple-choice

I have a list view that displays records from a database. Each row in the listview has a checkbox. How do I...

1. Create a toast message displaying the value of the selected item?
2. Identify the records selected by the user in the listview?
3. Iterate through each selected item and delete only the rows selected in the listview from the database?

I've been following this helpful tutorial here: //http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

```
public class PhoneNumberDataBaseListView extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        NumbersDataSource datasource = new NumbersDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        String number = "123";
        datasource.createNumber(number);
        List<Number> values = datasource.getAllNumbers();
        ArrayAdapter<Number> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Number>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void deleteNumber() {
        NumbersDataSource datasource = new NumbersDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        ListView LV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        List<Number> values = datasource.getAllNumbers();
        ArrayAdapter<Number> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Number>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = LV.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {
            if(checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
                Number item = adapter.getItem(i);
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, item.getNumber().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
             }  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method getCheckedItemPositions() returns SparseBooleanArray that indicates which items are checked (if item on specific position is checked, method valueAt(position) invoked on that array returns true). Class DBAdapter from tutorial you are following provides you with deleteTitle(long rowId) method which you should use to acheive what you want.Therefore your code should look more or less like this:

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++) {
    if(checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
        db.deleteTitle(adapter.getItemId(i));
     }
}
```

Of course SimpleCursorAdapter and DBAdapter should be stored in object attributes so that you have access to them from both methods (onCreate and deleteRecord). By the way, View parameter passed to deleteRecord method is not needed.

Comment: hello, thanks for your comment.. the tutorial i was originally following ended up not working for me so I started using another tutorial, however I am still unable to delete the items selected in my list view, or even get the values of the selected items... i've updated my code and the tutorial URL.